# What is the relationship between the NetStandard.Library NuGet package and the Target Framework in project properties?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I have a .NET Standard class library project. I want the library to be available to the broadest array of consuming applications, so following Microsoft's advice [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), I am targeting .NET Standard 1.3 in my project properties.

However, there is also a NuGet package called `NetStandard.Library`. And somewhere along the line, my project got a reference to this as well. What's more, it's a different version (1.6). I'm confused. Is this okay?

What is the relationship between these?

Comment: netstandard1.3 is a indicator for .NET CLI toolset, while `NETStandard.Libary` adds a bunch of references. They are there for different purposes, per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#official-artifacts "The NETStandard.Library metapackage (source) describes the set of libraries that define (in part) one or more .NET Standard versions."

Comment: @Lex, thank you. So if definitions for one or more .NET Standard versions are included, then does that mean that as long as the version of the NuGet package is >= the version named as your target platform, that you are good?

Comment: The version number is irrelevant. For example, even if your project targets netstandard2.x you use the same NETStandard.Library reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And somewhere along the line, my project got a reference to this as
>   well. What's more, it's a different version (1.6). I'm confused. Is
>   this okay? What is the relationship between these?

I think you should not worry too much about that.

`1.6.1` is just the version of `NetStandard.Library` nuget package and it has nothing to do with the version of the target platform, and they don't interfere with each other.

The `NetStandard.Library` nuget package just service the related net standard project and provide any libs and apis to develop,build, debug the current project.

**Besdies**, `NetStandard.Library 1.6.1` service net standard 1.x project while `NetStandard.Library 2.0.3` services net standard 2.x projects.

So when you finishing developing it and pack your net standard 1.3 lib project as nuget package and then use it in target platform, actually, `NetStandard.Library` nuget package already finish its job and it is irrelevant in this step.

**When** you use such net standard project into other target platform projects, you only need to consider that whether the net standard version and the target platform version are within the scope of support as your linked document describes.

**--------------Update 1-------------**

**Actually**, sure.`1.6.1` version is just only  the nuget package version.  `NetStandard.Library 1.6.1` nuget package defines one or more standard.net version libraries.

**And as far as I know**, `1.6.1` version supports net standard 1.0~1.6 class library projects and the nuget package services for those net standard version.

And then it will direct the current project to the corresponding target platform projects.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Let me see if I understand correctly. The `NetStandard.Library` NuGet package is purely there in support of whatever target framework you are targeting within project properties. So the "master," so to speak, is still the chosen target framework. Does that all sound correct?